# How to get next post and previous post URL in loop, single.php My WordPress 4.9.6

Tags: theme-development, next-post-link

I want to show next previous button in single.php  please suggest me the possible way, I'm stuck at these point in my site development

**Next**

**Previous**

```
> <?php posts_nav_link(); ?> <?php
> posts_nav_link('separator','prelabel','nextlabel'); ?> <?php echo
> get_next_posts_link(); ?> 
> 
> Default Usage
> 
> <?php echo get_next_posts_link(); ?>
```

just want to add links in these buttons please suggest me the best way and links need to add in the loop.

I have tried basic functions but can't get output as i want

Comment: "I have tried basic functions but can't get output as i want" What have you tried and what was wrong with them. If you don't include that information you're just going to waste people's time suggesting things you've already tried.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have updated now

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to get a link to next/previous pagination results on a single(single.php) view which it doesn't make sense to me.
Please refer to the docs:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link

For archive view:

> For displaying next and previous pages of posts see next_posts_link()
>   and previous_posts_link().

For single view:

> For displaying next and previous post navigation on individual posts,
>   see next_post_link() and previous_post_link().